# TeamCity publish using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

I've read many articles on publishing from TeamCity using various versions of Visual Studio.  I'm currently using v.9.1.7 of TeamCity and Visual Studio 2015.

I have my 3 build steps on check-in:

- Clean & Rebuild
- Unit Test
- Publish

[image: Build Steps]

When I check in my files I get a Tests Passed success message:

[image: Tests Passed]

I can tell from here something isn't right as I'm expecting it to say something about publishing.  When I look at the Build Log I see the following:

> **[12:48:22][API\API.sln] Publish [12:48:22][Publish] MSBuild [12:48:22][MSBuild] API\API\API.csproj: Build target: Publish
>   [12:48:22][API\API\API.csproj] _DeploymentUnpublishable**

My Publish Build Step is setup this way:

[image: Publish Build Step]

In my API project in Visual Studio I can publish to the correct location on the network.  Here is my publish profile:

[image: Visual Studio Publish Profile]

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I'm expecting the Publishing build step to work like when I click the Build->Publish menu item in Visual Studio.

I'm guessing that I'm missing something or misunderstanding what the publishing build step is supposed to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this will fix the problem, but the 'targets' field in your publish step should have the targets separated by a space or semicolon according to the comment e.g. `Rebuild;Publish`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get it to work after days and days of searching.  I found part of the answer here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740592/msbuild-publish-website-without-using-publish-profile).  The trick was to get it to work from the MSBuild Command Line:

> C:\TFS\project\myProject\APIproject>msbuild apiproject.csproj
>   /p:DeployOnBuild=true
>   /p:PublishProfile="Properties\PublishProfiles\DEV.pubxml"
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0

Once I got this running several times I was able to create a Build Step in Team City (see this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281987/how-do-i-get-this-command-line-script-to-work-in-teamcity)) and I set the following:

- Build file path: `<location of the apiproject.csproj>`
- MSBuild version: Microsoft Build Tools 2015
- MSBuild ToolsVersion: 14.0
- Run platform: x86
- Command Line Parameters: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile= "C:\TFS\API\API\Properties\PublishProfiles\DEV.pubxml" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0`

Comment: where do I set the "Build file path"?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, publishing from TeamCity requires certain files or alternatively VS installed on the build agent (which really isn't recommendable). Have you copied the necessary files to the build agent?

Comment: What is IIRC? Right now everything is on my local machine.  So technically I have VS where TC is.   Once I get this all dialed in I do plan on moving it to it's own box.

Answer (score 1):

Where are artifacts location defined.
And you can use Tentacles for publishing build into various environments.
I guess, you need to look towards artifacts configurations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSBuild runner to Deploy your Application/API [image]

Add Command line parameter :

```
/t:Clean /p:DeployOnBuild=true /t:build /t:publish /p:PublishProfile=C:\_works\teamcity\publishprofiles\Publiush_Profile.pubxml /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

PublishPrfile URL should be your publish profile path.

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

VS will probably find your publish profile with just the name, like:
`/p:DeployOnBuild=true;/p:PublishProfile=DEV;` very useful if you run more than one build agent.

And if you're deploying to an IIS you might need to add `AllowUntrustedCertificate=true;`