# How to publish binaries and copy to server in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, build-definition

We were using xaml builds earlier now we migrated to TFS2017. I am not able to publish the build files and how can we copy them.

My Build runs file it does not publish files. I see only the code files.

Comment: How's your build definition like?

Comment: Its A Webapi Solution file where we need to build and publish the binaries and then copy to the website folder where its hosted.

Comment: Dot net 4.0 application and just simple build and publish and then copy files to the location where site is hosted

Comment: [link] https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aka0TCUmpeyWjSlkwlYv414xYEsS

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) task and [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts) task in your build definition, to copy and publish files:

[image]

Comment: Yes i have done the same as in the image below but its not generating but build completes successfully.

Comment: @SheikhJunaid How did you specify the arguments in task `Copy Files` and `Publish Build Artifacts`? Please check [this website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) to specify appropriate arguments using match patterns.

Comment: @SheikhJunaid Please notice folders like Build.BinariesDirectory are reserved paths that you can use to override the default build outputs specified in the projects. The output of a build won't go into Build.BinariesDirectory by default.

Comment: What is the default path where i can look. Also What should be the change i need to make to publish binaries in a particular file. Later i can use copy files task to copy them to respective locations

Comment: If you run your project locally, where are the binaries going?

Comment: i created the profile and its creating the binaries there if i do manually on my local system

Comment: The location of variable $(Build.BinariesDirectory) on your build agent is  C:\agent\_work\8\b, you could check this folder to see whether there is binaries. If they are not there, check folder C:\agent\_work\8\s, to see where they locate and share the path.

Comment: I checked both these paths on build controller server and both are empty. And having the code files likes as in TFS not the published files.

Comment: Is C:\agent_work\8\s empty? According to your log file, build agent get sources to this folder. You could queue another TFS build, and check where the source downloaded and check the files.

Comment: Yes this folder is having TFS Source files. But i dont see publish binaries getting generated anywhere. @Cece Dong

Comment: How about location like C:\agent_work\8\s\project\bin\Debug?

Comment: Not there as well.. I see code files under S\Project

Comment: So it seems your build doesn't generate binaries. Please try to build your project on your build agent machine with MSBuild command line, to see whether it generate binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may create the publish profile for you web project and use it in build process. I use this way for the web site project:

1. Create the publish profile for project to package: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Add publish args for the build step. In my case:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Test" /p:PublishProfile="shdemowebtest - Web Deploy"

[image]

3. Then copy drop artifact

In your case you may create profile to publish on the file system. Then add build args to publish and redirect the destination folder: [MsBuild publish website without using publish profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740592/msbuild-publish-website-without-using-publish-profile)

**Steps for publish to local folder (on VSTS and local build agent):**

1. Add new profile to your project (destination bin\release\PublishOutput):

[image]

2. I use first build step to build additional project with tests.

[image]

3. Add step to publish with default folder path.
   MS Build Args:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:PublishProfile="FolderProfile"

[image]

3.1. Then I use standard step to copy results to staged directory:

[image]
 3.2. And publish to drop artifact:

[image]
 3.3. Then you can use that artifact to deploy with release management:

[image]

4. Add step to publish to custom path:
   MS Build Args:

   > /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:PublishProfile="FolderProfile" /p:publishUrl="C:\temp\Output"

[image]

4.1. The result of this step:

[image]

Comment: This is for VS2013 using the xaml. I need for vs2017 where the builds dont have the xaml and it failed when i tried to so these steps in command line as ms build arguments..Can you please add screenshots what i need to write on to get the binaries published.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful...I added same steps.  I am getting this meesgaed now after Build completes

C:\agent\_work\8\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
The Folders are empty. Is this folder on Build Server.

Also why you have again solution build after files copy. Do i need to add it as well.

Instead of Artifact publish location in your images i have artifact type which is having two option **Server**  and **File Share** @Shamray Aleksander

Comment: "Also why you have again solution build after files copy". No. this is just example

Comment: "i have artifact type which is having two option Server and File Share". My builds on Visual Studio Team Services. For TFS I also have **Server** and **File Share**