# Web.Config deleted from root in msbuild

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild

When deploying from a development to an acceptance IIS environment via FileSystem, the web.config file does not get output to root and as a result, accessing the website produces an Runtime error.

`(The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.)`

When I check the deployment directory, the web.config isn't there, but instead, its located at the `bin/` directory.

I tried changing the file type to Content/ None / Resource and nothing happens.

Also tried to follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465342(v=vs.100).aspx) and disable transformation by adding a **TransformWebConfigEnabled** tag in my configuration, to no avail.

Publishing straight from Visual Studio works, however, due to restrictions in the company, I can only publish directly to development environments.

Comment: Check this case which may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246562/using-msbuild-to-execute-a-file-system-publish-profile

Comment: How do you deploy via FileSystem?  Why not use WebDeploy?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT it didnt work but i guess it's a step in the right direction. Maybe I can add a task which will copy the web.config to the root folder, or remove the task which is deleting the web.config

Comment: @chief7 It's made through a robocopy script. But it's automated via TFS-Build. I could copy the files manually, however I don't have write access to the prod server.

Comment: Why not use WebDeploy?  It seems like this would simplify the deployment and be more stable.