# Deploy asp.net mvc website with command on post-build event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

i want to deploy mvc web site that build with visual studio,to the specific folder location.
how can it done with project post-build event command.
[image]

when project build should publish website to the specific folder location.

Comment: Maybe try to use the publish feature, create a new profile and deploy it to a folder

Comment: i want to do it with post-build event.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16246562/1207195

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming project is building successfully & has resolved all external references.

**1. First set Target Location for a Directory like below image in web project:**

[image]

this is optional but better than change debug/release from build path again & again.

**2. Add something like below in Post-build events:**

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)\bin\*.*" "c:\check\"
```

Hope it helps.

**Update**

Is this asp.Net mvc Web project or website? Web project can set output path to bin as in step 1. If you don't want that command in step 2 need path of compiled code as first parameter & path where you need to copy as second parameter, wherever they are. It uses `copy` command which is as old as DOS & Linux. Refer
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490886.aspx for copy command.

Comment: bin doesn't contain relevant publish stuff.need to get publish contain.want to publish that web site. bin folder doesn't contain view scripts etc.. relevant items that use for publish a website

Comment: bin doesn't contain relevant publish stuff.need to get publish contain.want to publish that web site. bin folder doesn't contain view scripts etc.. relevant items that use for publish a website.as i mention in the question i want to publish website to the folder when debug or build the project.

Comment: Is this asp.Net mvc Web project or website? Web project can set output path to bin as in step 1. If you don't want that command in step 2 need path of compiled code as first parameter & path where you need to copy as second parameter, wherever they are.

Comment: asp.net mvc web project. Output path set to bin but that doesn't containing stuff that need to publish the site.i want to get all stuff need to publish a web.

Comment: Just try putting path of compiled project there whether it is debug or release accordingly for source.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Create a publishing profile for your project using deploy to file system as a publishing method
2. On your postbuild event call the msbuild.exe with the DeployOnBuild=true parameter specifying you publishing profile.

Comment: hi i done that one but thing is when build the project it doesn't stop the build after firing post-build event.it is hanging and not finish the build.have to  cancel the build manually.

Comment: call "$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe" "$(ProjectDir)test.csproj" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:PublishProfile=Pub

Comment: doesn't end up the build process when start the build

Comment: You might have some resource still locked esclusively from the visual studio build. But I must say that the scenario is not very common... I mean, using the publish a release version for any build requested. Not the standard behaviour anyway. Plus, it is a redundant build (one for Debug followed by one for release). It might be more sensible to create an external tool pointing to an msbuild command.