# MSBuild ignoring publish profile configuration

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-publishing

I'm trying to publish a bunch of web services and a web site via command line using MSBuild. When I publish, the web services publish successfully but my web site does n't upon checking the logs, I've realized that msbuild is ignoring the build configurations in the specified publish profile and is using the default configurations i.e. Debug|AnyCpu. I've roamed around SO and the internet and found some articles but none worked for me.

[Other SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246562/using-msbuild-to-execute-a-file-system-publish-profile)

I would like to be able to make MSBuild understand that I am trying to publish via the publishprofile. I tested the publish profile and visual studio and was able to execute a publish.

Here is my msbuild command

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MsBuild.exe "PATH_TO_PROJECT\PROJECT.csproj" /nodeReuse:false /nologo /p:PublishProfile="FolderProfile" /p:DeployOnBuild=True

Logs

> The target "_ConvertPdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets
>   (34,37)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored. The
>   target "_CollectPdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets
>   (34,70)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored. The
>   target "_CollectMdbFiles" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets
>   (41,38)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored. The
>   target "_CopyMdbFiles" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\Xamarin.Common.targets
>   (41,71)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored. Project
>   "C:\Git\DXT\DXT.UI.WEB.APP.DEVICES\Dxt.Web\Dxt.Web.csproj" on node 1
>   (default targets).
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Dxt.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a
>   valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. 
>   Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this
>   message because you are trying to build a project without a solution
>   file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that
>   doesn't exist for this project.
>   [C:\Git\DXT\DXT.UI.WEB.APP.DEVICES\Dxt.Web\Dxt.Web.csproj] Done
>   Building Project
>   "C:\Git\DXT\DXT.UI.WEB.APP.DEVICES\Dxt.Web\Dxt.Web.csproj" (default
>   targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\Git\DXT\DXT.UI.WEB.APP.DEVICES\Dxt.Web\Dxt.Web.csproj" (default
>   target) (1) -> (_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) ->
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Dxt.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a
>   valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. 
>   Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this
>   message because you are trying to build a project without a solution
>   file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that
>   doesn't exist for this project.
>   [C:\Git\DXT\DXT.UI.WEB.APP.DEVICES\Dxt.Web\Dxt.Web.csproj]
>
> ```
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.09

I tried supplying a specific configuration to avoid the Debug|AnyCpu combo but encountered errors since the website has a custom Configuration called Release.Custom and depends on projects that do not have that configuration.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters this, I was able to fix my error by changing the value of the Configuration tag to my custom BuildConfiguration i.e. "Release.Custom". It's very stupid considering I've spent a day on this.

Comment: Thanks Leo, I just did, it doesn't let me accept the answer before 2 days