# Azure Devops Build Pipeline - files are not published

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, publish-profiles

I'm trying to publish my application using a VS publish profile.  When I publish through Visual Studio it works successfully, but through DevOps the publish does not work.  The build is successful in both.  Here is my VSBuild task definition:

```
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/t:Restore /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PublishBaseUrl=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? How's your issue going?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/p:publishUrl` instead of `/p:PublishBaseUrl`. If it still doesn't work, share your pubxml file and DevOps build log.

Answer (score 0):

You are using publish profile, so you could specify the MSBuild argument like this: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=myprofile`

Related thread: [Using msbuild to execute a File System Publish Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246562/using-msbuild-to-execute-a-file-system-publish-profile)